# How to change from Windows to Unix style End Of Line markers?

Tags: c#, string

How do I change the default newline character from Windows `\r\n` to Unix style `\n`?  Ideally I change the Environment somehow and have it done globally so I don't need to modify a bunch of string/textwriter code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not really doable.  The primary way by which developers embed new lines in their application is by using `Enviornment.NewLine`.  This is a static property which returns Window style new lines

```
public static string NewLine {
  get { 
    return "\r\n";
  }
}
```

There is no way to modify the return of this property from your code.

Your best option for changing new line endings is to develop a library which converts known sources of embedding Windows new lines to unix ones.  For example a stream and string converter would likely be in order.

Comment: So basically, search and replace or grep away the /r/n's write before placing the file to disk.  I'm not reading these values in, but am creating them on the fly from XML sources.  Is there perhaps an easy overload that I could use of the StringBuilder or TextBuilder classes?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Unfortunately there is no overload that I'm aware of.  You'd essentially have to implement them mostly from scratch.  But yes the general strategy would be to find windows endings and replace them in the stream / string on the fly

Comment: Bleh - at least I have a good point in code for this write before writing out the textfile.  Thanks for the quick and timely answers.